# WPF 4 touch events getting the center of a pinch gesture

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, gestures

I am using the .net 4 beta 2 touch libraries, and Im trying to implement a zooming feature in my WPF application.

I can get the zooming working just fine, but what I want is to zoom in on the center of the pinch gesture, and I cannot see anything in the API's about how to accomplish this.

Is there some methods or properties that expose the 2 contacts being using in the pinch gesture so that I can get the center of them?

**EDIT:**

I just investigated using the `GetIntermediateTouchPoints` method of `TouchEventArgs` which did not seem to give me what I want.

Thanks a lot
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the properties I was after was right in front of me all along.

the `Manipulation2DDeltaEventArgs` class has `OriginX` and `OriginX` properties that specific the center point of the pinch gesture, so Im just using that and its all good :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the new `TouchXxxxEvent` routed events, they all take [`TouchEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.toucheventargs(VS.100).aspx), which has [`TouchDevice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.toucheventargs.touchdevice(VS.100).aspx) property. If you call its [`GetTouchPoint()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.touchdevice.gettouchpoint(VS.100).aspx) method, you can get the [`TouchPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.touchpoint(VS.100).aspx) that represents the point of touch.

More [details and sample code](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/archive/2009/11/04/introduction-to-wpf-4-multitouch.aspx) from Jaime Rodriguez.

Comment: I am using the `TouchDown` event at the moment, but Im using the `ManipulationDelta` for the actual manipulation. I can see the `GetIntermediateTouchPoints` method, which could be what im after here...

Comment: Nope that method does not seem to do what I want, so for now I may have to track the contacts then calculate the distance between the two of them...ugly!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for .Net 4 release version.

In the case of using `ManipulationDelta` event the `ManipulationDeltaEventArgs.ManipulationOrigin` contains center point of the pinch gesture. The coordinates are relative to the `ManipulationDeltaEventArgs.ManipulationContainer`, which could be set in the handler of `ManipulationStarting` event.

Example code:

```
private void object_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    // If this was a multitouch gesture 
    // (like pinch/zoom - indicated by e.DeltaManipulation.Scale)
    // the following line will get us point between fingers.
    Point position = e.ManipulationOrigin;
    ...
}
```