# Is there any way to invoke holding event in wpf while long press the control as like in UWP?

Tags: wpf

I have searched a lot in internet and found that there is a event called OnHolding() in WinRT and UWP platforms which will invoke when we long press the control. But there is no such event in wpf. So anyone please tell me is there any way to handle such event in wpf or not?

Comment: Different question, the answers might provide you some direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108353/wpf-4-touch-events-getting-the-center-of-a-pinch-gesture

Answer (score 1):

There are `MouseDown()`, `MouseUp()`, `TouchDown()` and `TouchUp()` events.  If you have a property:

```
private DateTime timeOfHoldStart { get; set; }
```

which is set to `DateTime.Now` on `MouseDown()` or `TouchDown()`, on `MouseUp()` or `TouchUp()` you could compare the length of hold with a minimum value

```
if(DateTime.Now.Subtract(timeOfHoldStart) >= new TimeSpan(0,0,1))
{
    // Do your stuff..
}
```

Note, see https://wpf.2000things.com/2013/02/05/749-handling-the-touchenter-and-touchleave-events/ about the quirks of touch events, for example if you slide your finger into a control, `TouchDown()` doesn't get fired, but `TouchEnter()` does.